# Ignore all NUnit tests in a file

Tags: nunit

I can add an attribute on a test to ignore it:

```
[Test]
[Ignore("Foo Bar")]
```

Is there a way to ignore all tests in a file (at the TestFixture level)?

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Simply don't apply the TextFixture attribute on the class.

Comment: By not applying the attribute you're ignoring the fact that there are test methods within this class that aren't being tested for a reason. You should use [TestFixture, Ignore("reason")] to supply the output of the test results with a reason why they're ignored. Deleting/removing it is obfuscating the reason altogether when it probably makes sense to convey this to other developers.

Comment: +1 @Chris...Ignore attribute conveys purpose much more clearly.

Comment: This is incorrect as of NUnit 2.5, the TestFixture attribute is optional in most cases - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer with -10 votes atm..?

Answer (score 87):

```cs
[TestFixture, Ignore("reason")]
public class YourTestFixture { }
```

Or if you prefer to break your attributes out to one per line:

```cs
[TestFixture]
[Ignore("reason")]
public class YourTestFixture { }
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The currently accepted answer is technically also correct, but leaves you in a state of having dead code you don't know about (reason is in the comments on that answer). With newer versions of NUnit 2.5+, the accepted answer is actually wrong because the TestFixture attribute is optional. See http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5

Comment: `[TestFixture]` is no longer required so just putting `[Ignore]` is enough.

Answer (score 9):

As suggested, the `[Explicit]` attribute works well.  You can also simply place the `[Ignore()]` attribute under the `[TestFixture]` attribute, as shown in the documentation:

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=ignore&r=2.5

Use `[Ignore()]` if you want the test to be flagged as ignored (and therefore you get the yellow bar if all other tests pass).  Use `[Explicit]` if you want the test to be completely discounted (and therefore you get the green bar if all other tests pass).

Answer (score 1):

Before NUnit 2.5, removing the `[TestFixture]` attribute from the class seems like it would work.

This is not the case for NUnit 2.5 and later in which the `[TestFixture]` attribute is optional for non-parameterized non-generic fixtures. See [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.6.2) for more.

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken. The redirect seems to redirect back to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the whole `TestFixture` "on-demand" by using the `[Explicit]` attribute. Then it's there when you want it, but only when you explicitly click on it.